# How to render data from api like this

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

How do I render data from this api
I want to render Advice from this api

```
    fetch("https://api.adviceslip.com/advice")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [advices, setAdvices] = useState([]);
  console.log(advices); // you should have the fetch data here

  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://api.adviceslip.com/advice');
      const data = await response.json();
      setAdvices(data.slip);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return <></>;
}
```

Comment: The thing is that i have already done this much work but when I try to show the advice on screen it shows all the errors cause of data is in array inside array....

Comment: In order to help you, please provide more code to the question. Add how you are getting the data, I mean that array inside array

Answer (score 0):

In plain JS, see the code below or try this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYUwLgxgFgFARFMYAOBnAXAekwQ2QSwDocATAN3whFQBt9lCIB7AW13MpDgEoAoAAn6EwUEADsYAJ2rImY1CH4BeAHz9pqWfJCEAVqjkxufQcNESSOMDmVqA3gMH9m8pjR00mAcxgByAMoArhBUqBi+ADT8ltbcANyOAL4mQhBW0DAwIJKSTJLctvwOTs5yBu6E2bmSfgCiOXnokfxVefFJ7YJAA)

```
fetch("https://api.adviceslip.com/advice")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    console.log('Success:', data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```